# Automatically adjust parameter based upon machine time

Tags: sql, oracle, machine-learning, plsql

I am looking for kind of "machine learning" algorithm which dynamically adjusts a parameter based upon pre-defined criteria:

Assume I have following data:

```
Iteration   Batch_Size      Elapsed Time
  1            1000              10
  2            1000              11
  3            1000              10
```

My criteria is : "if average elapsed time for most recent iterations is less than 60 seconds, double the size"

Since average elapsed time for most recent 3 iterations is less than 60 seconds, the batch size can be increased to 2000. The next 3 iterations could be as follows

```
  4            2000              20
  5            2000              31
  6            2000              30
```

And we continue this process. If the elapsed time has exceeded 60 seconds, then we fall back to previous value as follows

```
 120           32000             121
 121           32000              93
 122           32000             113

 123           16000              51
 124           16000              54
 125           16000              61
```

Are there any PL/SQL or SQL libraries available ?

thanks

oradbanj

Comment: Could you explain how many operatons is "most recent" ? 2, 3, 5, 10, or maybe 10000 ?

Comment: 3 operations can be considered most recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to simulate your elapsed time by varying a random number based upon the previous elapsed time value. I then used a windowing function (avg) to calculate the average elapsed time over the current and previous 2 elapsed times. The **ADJUSTED_BATCH_SIZE** is reflecting the varying **AVERAGE_ELAPSED_TIME**. Because this is using a random number, it generates a different result set each time. Try running it a few times and see if you get what you expect.

```
WITH
    build_data (iteration, batch_size, elapsed_time)
    AS
        (SELECT 1 iteration, 1000 AS batch_size, TRUNC (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (25, 120)) elapsed_time
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT iteration + 1
              , batch_size
              , CASE
                    WHEN elapsed_time > 60
                    THEN
                        TRUNC (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (25, 70))
                    ELSE
                        TRUNC (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (25, 120))
                END
           FROM build_data
          WHERE iteration < 1000),
    calc_data
    AS
        (SELECT iteration
              , batch_size
              , elapsed_time
              , ROUND (
                    AVG (elapsed_time)
                        OVER (
                            ORDER BY iteration ROWS 2 PRECEDING
                        )
                )
                    average_elapsed_time
           FROM build_data)
  SELECT a.iteration
    --   , batch_size
       , elapsed_time
       , average_elapsed_time
       , GREATEST (
               batch_size
             + (CASE WHEN average_elapsed_time < 60 THEN 1 WHEN average_elapsed_time > 60 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END * 1000)
           , 1000
         )
             adjusted_batch_size
    FROM calc_data a
ORDER BY iteration;
```

Comment: Great. Works ad expected.